# ERROR : Unknown field 'discussion' on type 'Mutation'. with Relay and React `useMutation` hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, graphql, relay, graphql-mutation

I'm facing an issue on which I don't find any way to solve on internet. Hoping someone could help me here :).

I've followed the Relay step-by-step guide to improve myself on Relay and GraphQL (https://relay.dev/docs/getting-started/step-by-step-guide/) but I'm facing this error when I try to execute : `yarn run relay-compiler --src ./src --schema ./schema.graphql`.

Here is my code :

```
import { get } from 'lodash';
import './App.css';
import graphql from 'babel-plugin-relay/macro';
import { RelayEnvironmentProvider, loadQuery, usePreloadedQuery } from 'react-relay/hooks';
import RelayEnvironment from './RelayEnvironment';

const { Suspense } = React;
const { useMutation } = require('react-relay');

// Define a query
const RepositoryNameQuery = graphql`
  query AppRepositoryNameQuery {
    repository(owner: "xxx", name: "xxx") {
      id
      name
      object(expression: "master") {
        ... on Commit {
          history {
            nodes {
              abbreviatedOid
              message
              committedDate
              additions
              author {
                name
                email
              }
              tree {
                entries {
                  name
                }
              }
            }
            pageInfo {
              endCursor
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

const SomeButton = props => {
  console.log(get(props, 'repositoryId'));
  const [commit, isInFlight] = useMutation(graphql`
    mutation AppCreateDiscussionMutation($input: CreateDiscussionInput!) {
      discussion {
        id
      }
    }
  `);

  if (isInFlight) {
    console.log('spinner');
    // return <Spinner />;
  }

  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        commit({
          variables: {
            input: {
              repositoryId: '1234',
              categoryId: '5678',
              body: 'The body',
              title: 'The title',
            },
          },
          onCompleted(data) {
            console.log(data);
          },
        });
      }}
    />
  );
};

// Immediately load the query as our app starts. For a real app, we'd move this
// into our routing configuration, preloading data as we transition to new routes.
const preloadedQuery = loadQuery(RelayEnvironment, RepositoryNameQuery, {
  /* query variables */
});

// Inner component that reads the preloaded query results via `usePreloadedQuery()`.
// This works as follows:
// - If the query has completed, it returns the results of the query.
// - If the query is still pending, it "suspends" (indicates to React that the
//   component isn't ready to render yet). This will show the nearest <Suspense>
//   fallback.
// - If the query failed, it throws the failure error. For simplicity we aren't
//   handling the failure case here.
const App = props => {
  const data = usePreloadedQuery(RepositoryNameQuery, props.preloadedQuery);
  const { repository } = data;
  const { name, object } = repository;
  const { history } = object;
  const { nodes } = history;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <p>{name}</p>
        {nodes.map(commit => (
          <>
            <p>{get(commit, 'author.name')}</p>
            <p>{get(commit, 'message')}</p>
          </>
        ))}
      </header>
      <SomeButton repositoryId={get(repository, 'id')} />
    </div>
  );
};

// The above component needs to know how to access the Relay environment, and we
// need to specify a fallback in case it suspends:
// - <RelayEnvironmentProvider> tells child components how to talk to the current
//   Relay Environment instance
// - <Suspense> specifies a fallback in case a child suspends.
const AppRoot = props => {
  return (
    <RelayEnvironmentProvider environment={RelayEnvironment}>
      <Suspense fallback={'Loading...'}>
        <App preloadedQuery={preloadedQuery} />
      </Suspense>
    </RelayEnvironmentProvider>
  );
};

export default AppRoot;
```

Thank you very much everyone !

Regards,
Sourouche

Answer (score 1):

I've finally found what didn't work on my code !

It was just this little piece of code :

```
const [commit, isInFlight] = useMutation(graphql`
  mutation AppCreateDiscussionMutation($input: CreateDiscussionInput!) {
    createDiscussion(input: $input) {
      discussion {
        id
      }
    }
  }
`);
```

I've just forgot that I must re-specify the mutation I want just below my own named mutation. So, I used `AppCreateDiscussionMutation` as my own named mutation and I specify the `createDiscussion` mutation from github graphQL options.

Hope it is clear.
Thank you everyone.

Sourouche.